# App crashes on start up due to shared preferences

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

The application now is crashing due to nullpointerexception. I have found many different similar problems on google, however, none of the solutions worked. This app is supposed to forward a call, where the number to receive the forwarded calls are stored within the shared preferences. As for the numbers to forward are stored within a database. If possible, do guide me on how to get data from the database as well. Thanks

These are the logcats:

```
 02-12 15:09:07.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4827): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-12 15:09:07.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4827):     at com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
    02-12 15:09:07.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4827):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5158)
    02-12 15:09:07.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4827):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    02-12 15:09:07.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    02-12 15:09:07.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4827):     ... 11 more
```

This is my mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Switch switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
SharedPreferences preferences;

preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final String streditText1 = preferences.getString("Number", "");
editText1.setText(streditText1);


// set the switch to OFF
switch1.setChecked(false);
// attach a listener to check for changes in state
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    if (isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Forwarding is activated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        callforward("*63*" + streditText1 + "#"); // 0123456789 is the number you want to forward the calls.; 
        }
      else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Forwarding is deactivated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       callforward("#81#");

      }
  }
});}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

public void manage_numbers_onClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Manage_numbers.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);

  } 

private void callforward(String ArrayString)
{
    //DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    //db.getAllContacts().toString();

    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
    this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    Uri mmiCode = Uri.fromParts("tel", ArrayString, "#");
    intentCallForward.setData(mmiCode);
    startActivity(intentCallForward);
}

 private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener 
 {
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;        

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
    {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state)
        {
            // phone ringing
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) 
        {
            // active
            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) 
        {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
            // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            if (isPhoneCalling)
            {
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

This is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:text="@string/checktoconfirm"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:text="@string/receivenumbertext" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/savebtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which line is line 33 ?

Comment: editText1.setText(streditText1);

Comment: Then your `editText1` does not exist in `R.layout.activity_main`. Post your layout file

Comment: The problem is not the preferences; it's that `editText1` is `null`. Post your layout file xml.

Comment: check your xml for edittext.

Comment: is there editText1 in xml?

Comment: did u try printing value of "editText1" & "streditText1" to see what is null? probably ur "editText1" value is NULL

Comment: Please check if R.id.editText1 is inside R.layout.activity_main layout;;

Comment: editText1 is from another xml file, not in activity_main

Comment: the shared preference is actually from another xml file and not activity main. So this means that I can't retrieve data from another xml?

Comment: that is the reson for the crash. you cannot use the xml item without inflating it. It will be null in that case.

Comment: the xml file is actually set_number_to_receive.xml

Comment: how do I indicate for the data to be retrieved from another xml file??

Comment: Please make it clear what you want to do. You are inflating one XML and accessing the members of some other xml. *Do you really think its possible*?

Comment: Oh Ok, I realised where is the problem already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no `@+id/switch1` in your layout; *findViewById()* will return null.

UPD: You probably would like to read [Re-using Layouts with <include/>](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: Is there any way to get the data from another XML file as the edittext1 is from another XML file

Comment: @user3197061 : where you are getting the data? you are just setting the edittext value. why you want to set the value of an edittext which is not even visible.

Comment: @user3197061 yes, there is (see UPD), but: what you specify in the xml is what the user sees and what the program can use; if you do not mention an ID in the XML, it's not there in the view hierarchy. And no, you cannot find controls shown in other activities.

Comment: Ok, so I use upd to solve this? Thanks a lot for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the value of "editText1" is Null which is causing the crash. Check and fix it to incluidng it properly in xml & referncing in the code to remove the crash